# Using XSLT to make XML (e.g.<price>10000</price>) display as 10,000?

Tags: xml, xslt

A simple problem that I was wondering if it could be done.

Comment: Do note that accepted answer isn't quite complete. The "format pattern" argument of [`format-number()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-format-number) XSLT function follows the `xsl:decimal-format` declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [xsl:decimal-format](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#format-number) element and format-number() function.

Comment: +1 This is the proper well defined formatting number mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the format-number function:

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(/price/text(), "###,###")'/>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/func_formatnumber.asp for a complete reference.

Comment: Awesome, but what is text()? Also I read the w3schools stuff, does '###,###' apply to any price value? Say if I had `<price>10000000000000000</price>` would it work? Or would I need more #?

Comment: It refers to the text between the element tags. I think it could be omitted in most modern xslt processors.

Comment: Please don't refer to w3schools.

Comment: Using /text() is generally bad practice. It has never been necessary in any XSLT processor. In fact it's a bad habit that has crept in recently, as a result of Query tutorials written before the XQuery spec was finalized. It's only needed if the element (price in this case) contains child elements as well as text nodes and you need to separate them.

Comment: The answer to the question what happens if you try to format the value 100000000000 using ###,### is not well defined in the XSLT 1.0 specification (which refers to the JDK 1.1 specification, which is almost unobtainable, but it you manage to get hold of a copy, leaves many questions unanswered). However XSLT 2.0 makes it clear that the value is output as 100,000,000,000

Comment: @kork: I think that references are not necesary wrong. Quoting w3schools would be wrong as it's copyrighted. As an information source it's quite unclear and inexact... And because XPath/XSLT are standardized by their own specification, we tend to quote that. This is an special case because the spec itself refers to JDK 1.1...

Comment: @kork: w3schools are not an authoritative source about XSLT and their examples are often not the best. It is much better to quote the W3C XSLT specifications -- then there would be no question habging in the air about the correctness of the quoted text.